# How to expand a frame inside a canvas in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I created a canvas and then a frame as a child of the canvas. I found, the I should not use `pack()` to put the frame in the canvas. I used

```
my_canvas.create_window(0,0,window=my_frame, anchor='nw')
```

But I would like my frame be resizable with my app. Thus, I think, I need to put something like `fill=BOTH, expand=YES` for my frame.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the height and width of the canvas window to match the width and height of the canvas. You want to do this every time the canvas changes shape, which can be done by using a bind on the `<Configure>` event:

```
import tkinter as tk

def onCanvasConfigure(e):
    canvas.itemconfig('frame', height=canvas.winfo_height(), width=canvas.winfo_width())

root=tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background="blue")
frame = tk.Frame(canvas, background="red")

canvas.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor="nw", tags="frame")

canvas.bind("<Configure>", onCanvasConfigure)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I also used this post for onCanvasConfigure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063868/scrollable-frame-does-not-resize-properly-using-tkinter-in-python

Comment: that tags = "frame" really important here